# How to replace NaNs by preceding values plus some constant , in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas example data frame

```
    id   age   
0   1     2   
1   4     NaN 
2 NaN     NaN   
3   5     16
4   6     21
5   7     NaN
```

expected output

```
id   age   
0   1     2   
1   4     7 
2 NaN     11   
3   5     16
4   6     21
5   7     26
```

here if i want fill missing age , with previous age + 5 , how to do that ?

Comment: You can use the pandas `shift` function to access prior values of a column

Comment: Are there only `NaN`s to the end of `DataFrame`? Or there are multiple `NaN`s between integers? Can you add more data?

Comment: and expected output?

Comment: You should be more specific as in : What do you do about the `NaN` in `id` column I believe.

Comment: question updated with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.age.ffill()+df.age.groupby(df.age.notnull().cumsum()).cumcount()*5
Out[539]: 
0     2.0
1     7.0
2    12.0
3    16.0
4    21.0
5    26.0
dtype: float64
```